# Realizar operações de JOIN em duas arrays de dados com o D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Estou preparando os dados para visualização e operações de visualização. Utilizo a biblioteca [D3.js](http://d3js.org).

A coleção de dados é:

```
{ "autores" : [
  { "id":1, "nome": "Fulano" },
  { "id":2, "nome": "Ciclano" }
  ],
  "livros" : [
    {"id": 1, "autor": 1, "titulo": "AAA" },
    {"id": 2, "autor": 1, "titulo": "BBB" },
    {"id": 3, "autor": 2, "titulo": "CCC" },
    {"id": 4, "autor": 2, "titulo": "XXX" },
    {"id": 5, "autor": 2, "titulo": "YYY" }
  ]
}
```

A operação tem que agir de forma similar a um JOIN no comando SQL, obtendo como resposta o seguinte resultado:

```
[
  {"id":1, "autor": { "id": 1, "nome": "Fulano" }, "titulo": "AAA" },
  {"id":2, "autor": { "id": 1, "nome": "Fulano" }, "titulo": "BBB" },
  {"id":3, "autor": { "id": 2, "nome": "Ciclano" }, "titulo": "CCC" },
  {"id":4, "autor": { "id": 2, "nome": "Ciclano" }, "titulo": "XXX" },
  {"id":5, "autor": { "id": , "nome": "Ciclano" }, "titulo": "YYY" },
]
```

Existe alguma forma de se fazer isso utlizando a biblioteca D3.js?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Se vc está tentando apenas gerar esse array final a partir dos dois arrays iniciais, basta fazer um mapeamento do segundo com o primeiro, e para isso não é necessário nenhuma biblioteca adicional. Segue sugestões de soluções:

1) Para cada livro, fazer uma substituição *in-place* filtrando o autor correto.

```
livros.forEach(function(d){ d.autor = autores.filter(function(g){ return g.id === d.autor })[0] });
```

Essa solução tem custo *O*(livros * autores), pois para cada livro, uma varredura no array de autores realizada (desencadeada pela função *filter*). Podemos melhorar...

2) Indexar os autores por id e iterar sobre os livros fazendo substituições *in-place*.

```
// Indexa autores
var autorMap = {};
autores.forEach(function(d){ autorMap[d.id] = d });
// Realiza substituição
livros.forEach(function(d){ d.autor = autorMap[d.autor] });
```

Essa solução tem custo *O*(livros + autores), pois primeiro itera-se sobre os autores indexando-os, e em seguida itera-se sobre os livros realizando a substituição através de uma consulta a custo constante.

Para sua segurança, sugiro uma solução final um pouco diferente...

3) Indexar os autores por id e iterar sobre os livros, clonando-os de forma segura, e retornando um *novo* array.

```
// Indexa autores
var autorMap = {};
autores.forEach(function(d){ autorMap[d.id] = d });
// Mapeia os livros para um novo array com livros modificados
var newArr = livros.map(function(d){ var c = deepCopy(d); c.autor = autorMap[d.autor]; return c });
```

Para entender mais sobre essas funções que demonstrei (forEach, filter, map) consulte a [documentação oficial da Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array). Inclusive a própria D3 [incentiva isso](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays).

Com respeito ao **join** que foi cogitado na pergunta, vale considerar o que de fato significa join para a D3. No excelente artigo de Mike, ["Thiking with Joins"](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/join/), lemos:

> Thinking with joins means declaring a relationship between a selection (such as "circle") and data, and then implementing this relationship through the three *enter*, *update* and *exit* states.

Perceba que o *join* define não apenas um relacionamento entre **seleções** (elementos do DOM) e **dados** (js arrays, objects, etc), como principalmente a *forma* como esse relacionamento é processado (através de três estados sequenciais).

Ou seja, isso está mais relacionado a um padrão alto-nível de manipulação de elementos -melhor, documento - do que a uma técnica baixo-nível de tratamento de dados. Inclusive existe um nome para isso: [Data-Driven Documents](http://d3js.org/)

Então, se vc está buscando soluções pontuais para problemas de manipulação de objetos, arrays ou dados em geral, deve-se primeiro pensar em como alcançar isso utilizando js nativo apenas, e em seguida buscar alguma biblioteca que forneça utilidades (como [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/)). De outra forma, se vc está buscando um novo paradigma de como manipular documentos (diferente do jQuery p.ex.), D3 é a resposta. E vc ainda ganha uma diversidade enorme de utilidades de brinde! ;)

Comment: Excelente esse artigo *Thinking with Joins*, é uma peça fundamental para entender a d3.

Comment: uma pena que o d3 nao implemente manipulação de arrays, ou 'data', é pessa fundamental no seu funcionamento. Por falar nisso por que o d3 não implementa uma busca ciclica em seu D3.selection.data =\

Comment: O D3 implementa várias manipulações de arrays interessantes ( vide [Array Operators](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays#array-operators)), porém ele não reimplementa soluções já nativas. Essa necessidade que vc expos seria uma solução interesante a se ter no cardápio. Talvez valha a pena sugerir na comunidade.